# Парсинг всего текста из html

Tags: html, python, парсер

Возникла необходимость написать свой краулер on Python. На данном этапе мне необходимо распарсить весь текст из html и удалить лишнее. Как вы понимаете, парсер должен правильно работать с разными сайтами, а у многих тэги с текстом различаются: на каких-то текст есть внутри title и h3/a, на каких-то внутри span. Как можно сделать универсальный парсер для текста? Использовать цикл и проверку на присутствующие в html тэги или есть вариант проще?

Comment: Вариант с использованием сторонних библиотек пойдет? BeautifulSoup позволяет достать весь текст как-то так: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html); print(soup.text)`.

Comment: Можно использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы доставать содержимое из тегов